What explosive is Adam Savage referring to that resulted in scrapping an episode of MythBusters?
Has anyone ever leaked the substance that Adam Savage said was too explosive and common to be made public knowledge on MythBusters and led to scrapping the episode?
In this video, Adam Savage says,

The scary answer and I won't give it much context is that we were looking at, I'm going to be as circumspect and broad as I can be for this, we were looking at the purported explosive power of a commonly available material. And, what we found was something so energetic when we executed it that we agreed not to talk about what we'd learned. It was common enough, easy enough to implement, easy enough to execute that we were like the world will not benefit from this knowledge.

Separately, Adam tells the story again here except this time he says explicitly that Kari, Grant, and Tory found it. Adam adds this time that the footage was destroyed, and that he volunteered the finding to DARPA.
He goes on to say, bomb technicians and EOD (explosive ordinance detection people) know about that "stuff."

There's plenty of common things that are seriously explosive.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=JAwt61A0Wlc&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fnerdist.com%2F&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logo - My gut instinct is that this story is bullsh*t. It changes from telling to telling depending on the audience and grows in the retelling. First it's dangerous and made from household chemicals, then it's one of the most powerful explosives they've investigated. Finally it's so powerful that he called DARPA and they asked him to censor it.

@Valorum good find, I updated the Q with that info.

Reddit
Wanting something more official, I asked on Reddit. I believe Reddit has identified the substance and corroborated the story, and identified the substance (TATP).
Corroboration and Denial
Brian Louden, a cast member on Mythbusters respond,

Hi, actual MythBuster here. You will never know. For reasons that are all over these posts. Just to clear a little up though. This was not a novel discovery, this is readily available information but at a time when the dark corners of the internet were harder to run across. The discovery was reported and the footage is one of two sets of footage destroyed before it left America. Footage was processed completely in Australia but some never made it. MythBusters constantly battles with the value of the information they put out. At the core it is entertainment. The information about an explosive existing is one thing. Leveraging a popular global platform to spread that information for a few bucks is another thing.

Reddit Speculation (TATP)
Since it was said to be readily available, the most upvoted suggested and overall comment on the Reddit Thread was by /u/TepChef26

The general consensus I've seen was it was Triacetone Triperoxide (TATP). It's a high explosive that's not only laughably easy to make with one trip to a grocery or hardware store, but it's also nitrogen free. Which means, in the days the show was being filmed, it wouldn't have been detectable by most explosive scanning methods.
Seriously though, yes it's incredibly easy to make but DO NOT TRY IT! It's got approximately 70-75% power of the same weight of TNT. Also it's very volatile, can be set off from heat, friction, static electricity, etc.

Thanks to YouTube you can find TATP here

One of the telling hints that it's at least an exaggeration is that "DARPA put out a request for civilians to design bombs that they would be really hard for them to deal with".
Searches for the DARPA request yields that this request went out (with slightly different wording) on 3/11/2016 https://www.darpa.mil/news-events/2016-03-11. This web page brought the DARPA request into the public news on 3/14/2016 https://www.defenseone.com/technology/2016/03/darpa-IED-bomb-tinkerers/126649/.  The above footage of Adam talking was taken at comic con, dated 3/16/2016 or 3/17/2016.
Odds are much greater that Adam saw a current event and worked it into his speech.  It seems unlikely that Adam would have to withdraw film footage shot months prior to the comic con to responding to a request made by Darpa 5 days prior to the comic con.
If the mythbusters team found an at-home explosive, odds are much greater that the legal team persuaded/forced the producer to not air the information; but, remember how mythbusters worked.  They took information that was already in some aspect of the public and attempted to verify / bust the idea.
The Anarchist's Cookbook was the go-to manual in the 1980's for homemade explosives.  It was poorly written and had many errors, but much of the information within it had some veracity.  Odds are the Mythbuster team was attempting to bust one of its explosive recipes.
My guess is that it failed to "bust" the recipie after they worked out the mistakes in the formula and the legal team killed the episode.  Then Adam use the current news to borrow the authority of DARPA about an item that DARPA would likely never confirm or deny.  However, if you really want to discover if Adam is lying, DARPA provided a $40,000 bounty for participating in the program, and you are only one FOIA request away from seeing if Adam or the Mythbuster team received payment for the information they provided.
That home items are explosive is not new news, but often it becomes forgotten information.  Grain silos have been exploding for nearly a century now, and any small, combustible particulate in the air will combust, with explosive results.  In fact, this is one of the main reasons (the other being mismanagement) for the fall of Imperial Sugar (a Texas based sugar producer) where the sugar explosion destroyed their factory and killed/injured at least 20 people.
And that's not accounting for the other home-produced chemical problems that don't really require much knowledge to produce (like mixing bleach with ammonia, which will produce potently toxic gasses, which occasionally poison and scar the lungs of people that take cleaning a bit too far).

"They took information that was already in some aspect of the public and attempted to verify / bust the idea." You're skipping over the refinement step, often after the busting, wondering what it would take to [achieve goal]. That refinement can lead to new information, which would very much be censorable if it is deemed dangerous to the public (due to the availability of the ingredients). The explosions listed in this answer (grain silos and sugar factory explosions) are decidedly not something the average person has access to.

Two or three times this answer also starts leaning into the "besides, there's other dangerous stuff that people already know about" (paragraphs 5 and 8), which is decidedly not a reason why a new option wouldn't be censored. No one (neither DARPA or a legal team) is going "oh well what's another public danger on the pile, amirite?", and the existence of these already known about public dangers doesn't help address the current question.

@Flater Flour and sugar are both readily available.  If you make any combustible powder fine enough (grinding) and put it in the air, it will be very explosive.  Just because this combination more readily occurs in industry doesn't mean it's denied to the household.  And your second comment seems to lean into the idea that it's a NEW explosive, when odds are it isn't a new explosive, as Mythbusters tends to investigate OLD myths to validate / bust them.  Yes, new items would be an issue, but a show like Mythbusters never created new myths, they investigated existing myths.

so, in 7th grade, one of the very first demonstrations my science teacher gave was explosive flour using a commercial paint can with the lid only slightly tapped down; a candle next to a 1/2 cup of flour inside the can;, and a 10 ' tube attached to the flour container to blow into to disperse the flour. Making that into something truly dangerous is an engineering experiment, but it could be done IMO. Not anywhere near the potential of the suspected TATP however

@Yorik You just need to scale it up.  https://www.csb.gov/imperial-sugar-company-dust-explosion-and-fire/ :)  And here is one for flour, https://www.kmbc.com/article/dust-collector-eyed-as-possible-cause-of-grandview-plant-explosion/3687320 just in case.  I lived near a grain silo.  It exploded, but without damage, as they are designed to explode somewhat safely.
